# Drupal 7 form only submits when logged in

Tags: forms

I've built a form with Drupal 7 FAPI and it works perfectly, but only when I'm logged in as an admin. Otherwise, if you try to submit it without being logged in the page just refreshes when submitted, the registration doesn't get captured in the DB and the page doesn't redirect to the thank you page. Does anybody have an idea of what might cause that behavior?

The site is running on a Windows IIS server, very much not my choice, if that helps in any way. Unfortunately it's not public right no so I can't post a link.

Comment: Post your form code?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but it keeps breaking up when I try to enter it and turns into jibberish

Comment: Highlight the entire code block and indent right, then paste it in with the indent (4 spaces or one tab indent).

Comment: Implement hook_permission , but post your code first so that we can really help :)